# How can i get wishlist id of a product using the product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, wishlist

How can I get the wishlist id of the product, which is an item id of the product?
I have added a configurable product to the wishlist and I want its item id.

Comment: A product can be added to the wishlist of many users. So it would not be possible to get the wishlist Id from the product ID.

Comment: Please explain a bit more about your question.

Comment: I got the solution. When product were loaded on wishlist i used to get item id which is the id in the wishlist for product.

Comment: Great to know that you solved the problem, but please explain your requirement in detail in future to get faster responses.

Comment: How can i update a product in wishlist? I want to change the product 1 to product 2. Both product 1 and 2 are configurable products.